# How can I run facebook app on Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have installed Android Studio but I can't find the way to run facebook app on emulator.

Here is the snapshot of running Android Studio:

[image]

This seems like an tool to develop app.

How can i run an existing popular app on emulator?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a emulator with the Google Apis. Then just log in with your google account, go to the PlayStore and download whatever you want.

Comment: open "ADV Manager", next "Create Virtual Device". And then when you're in the "System Image" section choose one that says: Android 8.0 (Google Play).  P.S - 8.0 was just an example, you can use the version you want

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Navigation bar is hidden in your android studio. You can make it active from the `view` menu in the toolbar. There will be an option to open `AVD Manager` in your navigation bar. Open it, Create a new Virtual Device and make sure that you are connected to the internet. Now you can download and run any android application in your virtual device same as an android phone.